# I have 1.3.2 version of jquery file in master page and 1.4.2 file in content page, will this disturb the css when the page renders?

Tags: jquery, css, master-pages

I have 1.3.2 version of jquery file included in master page and 1.4.2 file included in content page, will this disturb the css when the page renders?
 I have tab control on the page, the design is not comming as expected, css is not properly rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes instead of solving a problem, you should redesign your architecture. Why do you use two versions of the jQuery? Just simply update the version of Master Page to 1.4.2.

Having different versions of jQuery in one page is not possible. Because they both want to take the $ sign as their symbol and a concept named **name clash** happens. Parents never name two of their children with one name. That's a logical rule in real-world, but a required rule in computer world. If you include jQuery 1.3.2 in your page, and then add another link to jQuery 1.4.2 after that, the latest version of the jQuery wins and overrides the older version. 
You can check to see which version of jQuery is available in your browser by using:

```
$.fn.jquery
```

or

```
jQuery.fn.jquery
```

Comment: in real world we fave typical scenarios, hence the comment by saeed, is not valid